# extract date from datetime value in react js datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

i have to extract date from date time value in react js datepicker, i tried below code

```
 new Date('27/02/2023 11:00 PM').getDate
```

but it is not returning any value. how to extract value '27/02/2023' from datetime value '27/02/2023 11:00 PM'. i am using date-fns, and react datepicker [react datepicker demo page](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

Comment: Please create a [mre]. It's quite unclear what you're asking/trying.

Comment: above was the example.. my question was simple. how to extract date from timestamp.. what else you need?

Comment: Oke, well this has nothing to do with reactjs or datepicker. I'll link a dupe

Comment: Well, did you ment `getDate()` since it's a function?

Comment: Yes, but it will return only date..not month and year

Answer (score 0):

You already had `date-fns` so just take advantage of it.

`date-fns` provides `format()` function for you to format a datetime in timestamp or date-fns object to a string.

To extract value '27/02/2023', you can do like this:
`format(new Date('27/02/2023 11:00 PM'), 'dd/MM/YYYY')`

For other format, you can find more from [this docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format).